# Help with preparing Congo Red TSA

Tags: microbiology, lab-techniques, materials

So I want to make Congo Red TSA. My instructor gave some hints but I still have some questions:

1. I start by making two stock solutions: 20 mg/ml of congo red and coomassie in two different falcon tubes. To prepare 30 ml of each, would I dissolve 600 mg in sterile water?
2. The final concentation in a 500 ml TSA solution needs to be 40 μl/mL of CR and 20 μg/mL of coomassie. How do I calculate the amount of solution needed for the TSA?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, that's correct.

2) This is just a simple matter of applying the equation $C_1V_1=C_2V_2$. For congo red:

- $C_1=20\frac{mg}{mL}$
- $C_2=0.04\frac{mg}{mL}$
- $V_2=500\ mL$

I'm sure you and a calculator can figure the rest out.